# How to do a rolling sum in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given the column `A` as shown in the following example I'd like to have the column `B` where each record is the sum of the current record in A and previous record in B:

```
+-------+
| A | B |
+-------+
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 
| 1 | 2 |  
| 1 | 3 | 
| 0 | 3 | 
| 0 | 3 |
```

So in a way I would be interested into consider previous record into my operation. I'm aware of the `F.lag` function but I don't see how it can work in this way. Any ideas on how to get this operation done?

I'm open to rephrasing if the idea can be expressed in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to do a rolling sum of A. You can do a sum over a window, e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn('B', F.sum('A').over(Window.orderBy('ordering_col')))
```

But you would need a column to order by, otherwise the "previous record" is not well-defined because Spark dataframes are unordered.